# Sending input to an application

Tags: .net, vb.net, input

I'm using VB.net.  I need to send keystrokes to an application.  Is this possible?  I'm sure it is.  Can somebody give me a shove in the correct direction?  I need to be able to do other things while this program is doing this!

Comment: What do you mean by "other things"?

Comment: Such as have the specified program in the background while I work on other things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into [SendKeys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.aspx).

Comment: This requires that the application is active though, I need to be able to do other things while this is all happening.  Is there anything that will allow me to send it a process or window handler to perform a similar task?

Comment: @DalexL you can use the [SendMessage()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644950(VS.85).aspx) WinApi to achieve that.

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about working with an application that's completely outside of your application domain?  If that's the case, you're going to have to get into Win32 API.  A good place to start is [pinvoke](http://pinvoke.net).

Or do you mean that you want your application to allow you to continue doing stuff while it does some heavy lifting on a different process?  In that case, look at [BackgroundWorker thread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xs8549b.aspx).

Without knowing what you mean by "other things" and "while this is all happening," it's hard to give you an accurate answer.

Answer (score 1):

A great tool that I've used for just this circumstance is 
[AutoIT](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/).